# Ember making get request to 'ost' instead of 'posts'

Tags: ember.js

an ember noob question -- in order to learn it I'm trying to make a simple blogging app. I'm trying to load an index of posts, but am getting the error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/api/osts
```

This makes sense, because it should be

```
http://localhost:3000/api/posts
```

What mistake am I making here? -->

```
Blog.Post = DS.Model.extend({});

Blog.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    this.get('store').findAll('post')
  }
})

Blog.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts');
});

Blog.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: 'Blog.ApplicationAdapter'
});

Blog.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'api'
})
```

Comment: I don't see any errors in the code you've posted here.  You've probably just made a small typo in your code somewhere.  Did you directly copy in paste this here or is there anymore code?

Comment: Try removing the `Blog.Store` section.  I don't think you need to do that any longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change

```
this.get('store').findAll('user');
```

to

```
this.get('store').findAll('User');
```

-.-